# Is a vector of weakly convergent sequences of random variables weakly convergent?

Tags: probability-theory

> Consider the following: we have $d$ relatively sequentially compact sequences $(X_{n,l })_{n=1 } ^{\infty } , \ l=1,...,d$ of random variables. I wonder if the random vector $(X_{n,1 },...,X_{n,d } )_{n=1 } ^{\infty}$ is relatively sequentially compact?

That a sequence of random variables is relatively sequentially compact means that for any subsequence there exists a further subsequence that converges weakly to some limit point. Thus in our situation by taking a subsequence such that the first sequence $X_{n,1 } $ converges and then a subsequence of that subsequence such that $X_{n,2 } $ converges etc we get a subsequence for which all the sequences converges, say to limits $X_1,...X_d$.

> Does it follow that $(X_1,..,X_d)$ is a weak limit of $(X_{n,1 } ,...,X_{n,d } )$?

If the statement is true would it be possible to show this directly from the definition that $\int f dP_{(X_{n,1 },...,X_{n,d } )} \to \int f dP_{(X_{n,1 } ,...,X_{n,d } )}$? for any continuous and bounded $f$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement about weak limts is false but the statement about weak sequential compactness is true. By Prohorov's Theorem weak sequential compactness  is equivalent to tightness and the  vector of your sequences is tight because product of compact sets is compact.

$X_n \to X$ weakly and $Y_n \to Y$ weakly does not imply $(X_n,Y_n) \to (X,Y)$ weakly.

Comment: Does this work of we don't assume that the sequences are independet? ie if we don't have that the probabilty measure of the random vectors is the product of the probability measures of the random variables?

Comment: Independence is not required for tightness and hence it is not required for sequential compactness.

Comment: No I mean that $X_{n,l } $ is tight means that for every $\epsilon $ there exists a compact set $K_l $ such that $P(R-K)<\epsilon $. But then knowing that $K_1 \times ... \times K_d $ is compact how do I relate the measure of $R^d-(K_1 \times ...\times K_d ) $ if we don't know that the measure of the vector is the product of the individual measures?

Comment: $(X_1,X_2,..,X_d) \notin K_1 \times K_2 \times ...\times K_d$ implies that $X_i \notin K_i$ for some $i$ and this is enough to prove tightness. (The probability is smaller than the sum of $d$ terms each of which has  small probability).